# Quiero usar SASS en un proyecto de Laravel 10, no entiendo si mi archivo .scss deberia reflejarse en tiempo real en un archivo .css?

Tags: css, laravel, scss

Estoy usando laravel 10, quiero integrar SASS, que ya lo instale, para modularizar los estilos de mi proyecto.
Los cambios que realizo puedo ver que se compilan bien en la terminal, tambien con el comando *run dev build* se me genera en la carpeta buil/assets/estilos-(letras que varian).css.
Mi pregunta es, fuera de Larave, hay una comando --watch estilos.scss:estilos.css, que hace que se relacionen y estilos.scss al escribir o cambiar codigo, tambien lo hace en la hoja , estilos.css, en tiempo real. Usando Laravel 10 (con vite, no laravel mix), se puede hacer algo asi donde la hoja de estilos se modifique y quede en la carpeta resources/css ?.